# Java - loop trough a csv file checking for missing meter readings based on the time stamp

Tags: java, loops, csv

I've got an csv file full of meter reading of a whole month - 24 meter readings a day to be exactly. Now i want to check if there really are 24 meter readings a day, because somehow there are some that miss.

My code:

```
public class CSVReader {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        String csvFile = "data.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ";";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                
                String[]text = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                System.out.println(text[0]);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've got the reader already done. Now i am stuck on programming the loop for checking if there is a gap in the timeline.

```
2020-07-30 00:00:00
2020-07-30 01:00:00
2020-07-30 02:00:00
2020-07-30 03:00:00
2020-07-30 04:00:00
2020-07-30 05:00:00
2020-07-30 06:00:00
2020-07-30 07:00:00
2020-07-30 08:00:00
2020-07-30 09:00:00
2020-07-30 10:00:00
2020-07-30 11:00:00
2020-07-30 12:00:00
                        <- missing meter reading at 13:00:00
2020-07-30 14:00:00
2020-07-30 15:00:00
2020-07-30 16:00:00
2020-07-30 17:00:00
2020-07-30 18:00:00
2020-07-30 19:00:00
2020-07-30 20:00:00
2020-07-30 21:00:00
2020-07-30 22:00:00
2020-07-30 23:00:00
```

My goal is it to get a kind of overview of that whole file in the console or in an external .txt file if something got missing.

For example the output:`2020-07-30: missing meter reading at 13:00:00`

So there should be listed every day where some measurements are missing and at the time where the are missing. I hope that i explained my problem and also i hope that there is somebody who can help me.

In addition here are some example timestamps in my file for testing reasons:

```
2020-07-29 00:00:00
2020-07-29 01:00:00
2020-07-29 02:00:00
2020-07-29 03:00:00
2020-07-29 04:00:00
2020-07-29 05:00:00
2020-07-29 06:00:00
2020-07-29 07:00:00
2020-07-29 08:00:00
2020-07-29 10:00:00
2020-07-29 11:00:00
2020-07-29 12:00:00
2020-07-29 13:00:00
2020-07-29 14:00:00
2020-07-29 15:00:00
2020-07-29 16:00:00
2020-07-29 17:00:00
2020-07-29 18:00:00
2020-07-29 19:00:00
2020-07-29 20:00:00
2020-07-29 22:00:00
2020-07-29 23:00:00
2020-07-30 00:00:00
2020-07-30 01:00:00
2020-07-30 02:00:00
2020-07-30 03:00:00
2020-07-30 04:00:00
2020-07-30 05:00:00
2020-07-30 06:00:00
2020-07-30 07:00:00
2020-07-30 08:00:00
2020-07-30 09:00:00
2020-07-30 10:00:00
2020-07-30 11:00:00
2020-07-30 12:00:00
2020-07-30 13:00:00
2020-07-30 14:00:00
2020-07-30 15:00:00
2020-07-30 16:00:00
2020-07-30 17:00:00
2020-07-30 18:00:00
2020-07-30 19:00:00
2020-07-30 20:00:00
2020-07-30 21:00:00
2020-07-30 22:00:00
2020-07-30 23:00:00
2020-07-31 00:00:00
2020-07-31 01:00:00
2020-07-31 02:00:00
2020-07-31 03:00:00
2020-07-31 05:00:00
2020-07-31 06:00:00
2020-07-31 07:00:00
2020-07-31 08:00:00
2020-07-31 09:00:00
2020-07-31 10:00:00
2020-07-31 11:00:00
2020-07-31 13:00:00
2020-07-31 14:00:00
2020-07-31 15:00:00
2020-07-31 16:00:00
2020-07-31 17:00:00
2020-07-31 18:00:00
2020-07-31 19:00:00
2020-07-31 20:00:00
2020-07-31 21:00:00
2020-07-31 22:00:00
2020-07-31 23:00:00
2020-08-01 00:00:00
2020-08-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: Why don't you work with a int counter that starts with your daily amount and decreases every time you make a println on the console with a string that is longer than 1?
Additionally you could print the missing entries and or throw an Exception.

Comment: That would be an idea, but I've got up to 30 days in one file with 24 meter readings each. How am I going to handle that?

Comment: Initialize the counter before your while loop to your value (24). In your loop you are checking if text[0] != null and text[0].length >= 1. If this is true you can decrease the counter (counter--;) and or make a print statement to the console where you can identify it more easily.

Comment: Can u make a more detailed answer with your idea? It would be very much appreciated, because i still don't know how to cope with the 700+ entries.

Comment: Looping is a basic programming skill. And Stack Overflow is meant to be a narrowly-focused problem-solution site, not a tutorial site. Oracle [provides a tutorial site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) free-of-cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...

```
int count = 24;
while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
  String[] text = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
  if(text[0] != null && text[0].length > 1){
    System.out.println(text[0]);
    counter--;
  } else {
    System.out.println("MISSING ENTRY");
  }
}

System.out.println("Missing entries: " + counter);
```

...

I think of something like this to get a better view. Does it fix your problem?

Comment: The output in the console is: Missing entries: -733 ... so there is something wrong with your code. I think because you keep subtracting the `int counter` even if `counter = 0`.

Comment: You are correct, I forgout about that. You should adjust the counter to 24 entries*30 days (or whatever size you need it to). If you want to check how many measurements per day are missing you could use another counter which resets itself after 24 iterations. (You can use % for that)

Comment: Ah alright! But i have another problem.... i always need to skip the first 6 entries of that file. Do you have any clue how i can do that? With a for loop it would be easy but i don't know how to do it with a while loop.

Comment: If you youse this counter I spoke about you can simply do an if-statement. if(counter%24) >6) or something like that